# Mutation and crossover operations in discrete differential evolutionary operations?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, heuristics, evolutionary-computing

I need to use discrete differential evolutionary algorithm for assigning discrete values from set size $L$ to vectors of size $D$ where $L$ could be smaller, equal or larger than $D$. Elements of vector $X$ could take the same values of other elements.  My question is if we have a population of size $NP$ with each vector $X$ in the population of size $D$. How do we actually apply the mutation operand:

$$V_{j,i}^{G+1} = X_{j, r_1}^{G} + F\cdot (X_{j, r_2}^{G}-X_{j, r_3}^{G})$$

where $i$, $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$ are references to vectors in $NP$ and none is equal to the other, $J$ is an index in vector $X$, and $F$ is a random number between $0$ and $1.2$.

Suppose $X_{r_1}^{G}$ is equal to $\{4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0\}$ and  $X_{r_2}^{G}$ is equal to $\{2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2\}$ and $X_{r_3}^{G}$ is equal to $\{1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1\}$
Could anyone explain in detail the steps (through example if possible) on how to get the mutant vector $V_{j,i}^{G+1}$

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single way in which one can approach a discrete optimization problem using [Differential Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution) (DE).

Widespread techniques listed under the Discrete Differential Evolution label aren't DE-specific.

You can allow variables to take values in a continuous range and use penalty functions to enforce integer values:

$$ \bar{f}(w) = f(w) - \sum_i{k_i \cdot (w_i - \operatorname{round}(w_i))^2} $$

$w$ is the vector of parameters (chromosome values), $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ the basic fitness function (here assuming "greater is better"), $k$ a problem-specific scaling vector, $\bar{f}(\cdot)$ the "penalized" fitness function.

In this way the DE algorithm (*DE/rand/1*) stays the same:

$$\begin{align}
X_{j,r2}^G - X_{j,r3}^G & = \{2,2,3,0,4,2\} - \{1,2,3,3,0,1\} = \{1,0,0,-3,4,1\} \\
F \cdot (X_{j,r2}^G - X_{j,r3}^G) & = 0.5 \cdot \{1,0,0,-3,4,1\} = \{0.5,0,0,-1.5,2,0.5\} \\
V_{j,i}^{G+1} & = \{4,1,3,2,2,0\} + \{0.5,0,0,-1.5,2,0.5\} = \{4.5,1,3,0.5,4,0.5\}
\end{align}
$$

The trial vector $U$ is obtained via crossover between the *donor vector* $V_{j,i}^{G+1}$ and a *target vector* $X$:

$$U_{j,i}^{G+1} = \operatorname{crossover}(V_{j,i}^{G+1}, X_{j,i}^{G})
$$

The *target vector* is compared with the *trial vector* and the best one is admitted to the next generation.

This is the recommended procedure with [R DEOptim Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html) (via the optional `fnMap` parameter).

---

You can round all the real-valued parameters before evaluating the fitness function:

$$\bar{f}(w) = f(\operatorname{round}(w))$$

(`round` acts as a *repair operator*)

This is the technique used by *Mathematica*'s functions [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) / [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) with the options `Method → "DifferentialEvolution"` and  [`Element[w,Integers]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)

---

There are also many variations of DE named *something*-Discrete-DE:

- **Binary Discrete Differential Evolution**: the solution of a problem is presented as a binary string instead of a real-valued vector
- **Real Value based Discrete Differential Evolution** introduces forward/backward transformations to map integer into real number
  and viceversa
- **Exchange based Discrete Differential Evolution**: here the crossover operator doesn't change but mutation, being the primary operator acting on
  elements of vector in continuous space, is replaced.
- ...

So you should specify what form of Discrete DE you're interested in for a step by step example.

Meanwhile [A Comparative Study of Discrete Differential Evolution on Binary
Constraint  Satisfaction Problems](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-comparative-study-of-discrete-differential-Yang/e9cf0a458442ff307ac7649e2327cf7958e35a79/pdf) by Qingyun Yang (2008 IEEE Congress on Evolutionary Computation) is a good starting point with many references.